# How to remove border/shadow from lollipop buttons

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop

The buttons looks fine for api < 21. However, the +21 versions creates this border or shadow that is shown on the image below. How do I get rid of it without changeing the hole theme, but setting a style variable?

[image]

It might be more clear on this colored image. There is some kind of border around the buttons.
[image]

My buttonssstyle is defined like this:

```
<style name="buttonTransparent" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">45dp</item>
    </style>

<style name="buttonLargeWhite" parent="buttonTransparent">
        <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: try to set  android:elevation="0dp" to your main layout.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Lollipop has a nasty little feature called `stateListAnimator` which handles the elevations on Buttons, which leads to shadows.

Remove the `stateListAnimator` to get rid of the shadows.

You have got multiple options to do that:

**Java:**

```
button.setStateListAnimator(null);
```

**Kotlin:**

```
button.stateListAnimator = null
```

**or in your layout xml's:**

```
<Button
...
android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
....
/>
```

Comment: An other idea is, to use Textviews instead of Buttons. They doesn't have such an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Mark the answer as "accepted" if worked. I'm happy that I could help you ;)

Comment: You can also use `button.setStateListAnimator(null);` for API Level 21 and higher

Comment: @mklimek absolutely right. I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I've been switching my Button's with custom backgrounds to TextView's. Thanks Google !

Comment: @oberflansch if you switch to TextViews you will lose some of the button's pre-confoigured accessibility features.

Comment: This leads to a native crash on certain Samsung devices. Just FYI for anyone who experiences it. Its good to utilize a theme instead.

Comment: @toobsco42 Your statement is incorrect. Tested on Android 5.0 Asus ZenFone and Android 5.1 Meizu Note 1. Didn't crush.

Comment: @JigneshShah Can you clarify at least API level of such Samsung devices?

Comment: `android:stateListAnimator` will remove all states (enabled, disabled, pressed and so on)

Answer (score 53):

Best and easiest way i am using is setting style attribute to Button

```
<Button
...
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
....
/>
```

may be someone need in future.

Comment: Is there a way to use this answer programmatically?

Answer (score 13):

There is already a style you can leverage not to have the borders.

apply

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
```

to your item to remove the borders

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this **globally** by setting `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` in `Resources\values\styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NoShadowButton</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NoShadowButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And voila the shadows are gone for good :)

Answer (score 8):

"shadow" effect is added on **Lollipop Appcompat theme**

add the following line in res/values-v21/styles.xml to remove default shadow

**Theme level:**

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
```

**xml layout:**

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

**Java:**

```
setStateListAnimator(null);
```

**Kotlin:**

```
stateListAnimator = null
```

Comment: `android:stateListAnimator` will remove all states (enabled, disabled, pressed and so on)

Answer (score 7):

Buttons in android have statelistAnimator property so by declaring it null we can remove the border of button

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Answer (score 3):

in xml we can use

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you just remove the shadow entirely, by setting the elevation to nothing.  Since you already have a XML style (add this to use this universally), or you could add this attribute to your XML view definition

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: I have tried to set the elevation but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to remove?  Elevation will remove the shadow (I think I am not clear)

Comment: I just added a second image that might make it more clear, what it is I want to remove. There is some kind of border/shadow around the button.

Comment: This will also mess up your layout if you used elevations elsewhere. You can alternatively try to set the outline provider via `outlineProvider="@null"`, but not sure if that would work.

Comment: @Booger Doesn't work on Android 8 on Button. But `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` does.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue**

1. From Android v21, Border has been added by default for all the button.

   ```
   <!-- Bordered ink button -->
   <style name="Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="background">@drawable/btn_default_material</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
        <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="minWidth">88dip</item>
        <item name="stateListAnimator">@anim/button_state_list_anim_material</item>
        <item name="focusable">true</item>
        <item name="clickable">true</item>
        <item name="gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
   </style>
   ```

   - The property "**stateListAnimator**" is the one which is causing the problem.

**Solution**

1. In our application theme, set button style to remove the default border (Android support library itself provides style for it).

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- From Android-v21 - Border has been added by default, hence we are removing it. -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless</item>
   </style>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically in Kotlin, you can do

```
button.stateListAnimator = null
```