# Preventing material button from raising in Android

Tags: android

As you know, buttons in API+21 raise when you touch them. According to the documentation, you should not place such buttons in dialogs or other raised interfaces. I have tried setting elevation to 0 or 1 but to no avail. I just want the button to have the ripple effect without raising.
How can I do that?

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Show your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003693/3090173. It says to set the button's stateListAnimator to null via the xml attribute.

```
<Button
   ....
   android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
   .... />
```

You can also set a custom drawable as the background to get rid of the elevation.