# Xamarin forms Image button issue

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

platform app using Xamarin PCL project. I have created a button with image and no text.

```
 <Button Image="{DynamicResource ProfileImage}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="dashboard" StyleId="dashboard" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="TabClicked"></Button>
```

I am facing some UI Issue.
In windows 10,it looks like -

[image]

In android, it looks like-

[image]

Is there any way to remove this outline border from android.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @Daniel yes but by setting buttons elevation to zero.

Comment: Add your answer and accept it. It may help some other people ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the border/shadow from buttons in Android by setting its elevation to 0px [with the help of this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003506/how-to-remove-border-shadow-from-lollipop-buttons)

```
class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            try
            {
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    Control.Elevation = 0;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `BorderColor="Transparent"` on your button XAML?

Answer (score 0):

To remove background of an image completely, you can use Image view type instead of Button.

You can arrange it's source:

```
<StackLayout Padding="15,5,0,5">
      <Image x:Name="MyImage"  Source="myImage.png"/>
</StackLayout>
```

And you can add a click method it easily:

```
var gestureRecognizerForImage = new TapGestureRecognizer();
gestureRecognizerForImage.Tapped += MyImageClicked;
MyImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(gestureRecognizerForImage);

 public async void GetMediaClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     await DisplayAlert("Clicked", "My Image is Clicked", "OK");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `BorderWidth = 0`. It should remove the border.