# What's the default value for View's StateListAnimator?

Tags: android

I set Button's StateListAnimator to null to disable elevation
(as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003693/6325722))

```
button.setStateListAnimator(null);
```

Now I need to set it back how it was.

Is there exact default value for StateListAnimator which I can use to set it back to default state?