# MaterialButtonToggleGroup remove default border

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button, materialbutton

I am new to android development and I need some help removing the borders from the MaterialButtonToggleGroup.

[image]

**Any help is appreciated**

**Edit**

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/companyName"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:checkedButton="@id/btnAll"
    app:singleSelection="true"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    android:gravity="center"
            >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAll"

        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="All"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"

      

        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnProgram"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        style="@style/ToggleButtonGroupStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"



        android:textSize="13sp"
         />
</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout

Comment: I have edited the post with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the button xml:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31003693/10277150

Comment: Is there a way to keep the bottom border but only remove the top and thank you that worked perfectly.

Comment: try this please : android:outlineProvider="bounds"
and check the link : [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477371/android-elevation-not-showing-a-shadow

Answer (score 1):

Use in your MaterialButton the `strokeWidth` attribute:

```
       <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
            app:strokeWidth="0dp"
```